# Do seatbelts reduce the risk of injury or death in buses?

Tags: safety, buses

While I was on a two hour bus trip in Tasmania, someone noted that I was the only passenger who was wearing a seat belt. Do seatbelts reduce the risk of injury or death to bus passengers? Is the reduction in risk significant in all scenarios, or does the bus and the road have to be really dodgy in order for a serious crash to be remotely likely?

Comment: It could be a case of CYA. In some countries (e.g. Sweden), seat belts are obligatory for all passengers in a vehicle (bar some special circumstances), including those in inter-city buses. While I can see the reason for obligatory seat belt use in a car, I'm not so sure they have much utility in a bus.

Comment: @mindcorrosive that's true in Australia as well. Also CYA for the bus companies as well, in case a crash victim wanted to sue because their bus didn't have seatbelts.

Comment: How is this a travel-specific question? The question is in my opinion to generic. skeptic.se would be more appropriate

Comment: @Andra if you're on a long-distance bus, you're travelling.

Comment: I agree that it fits better on Skeptic.SE, and I'd expect better answers there, but it's not off-topic on Travel.SE.

Comment: I don't see why this is travel-related, Physics SE would be the better place.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm If you are immigrating you are traveling, still expat and immigration questions do get closed here almost immediately (much to my dislike btw).

Answer (score 4):

The most common injuries in serious bus accidents seem to be when the bus turns over - at this point passengers can be thrown against the windows (which, being broken may mean they end up falling through onto the ground) or against the roof if the bus rolls.

A proper seat belt will prevent these accidents.

Why on earth wouldn't you want to wear seatbelts? Any safety feature is likely to be a good idea. Think of it this way: in what circumstance would you be better off **not** wearing it?

Admittedly statistics show that simple lap belts are not proven to improve safety for children, which is one reason why they aren't ubiquitous on school buses.