# Are seatbelts unnecessary or unhelpful for safety for passengers in a bus?

Tags: safety, driving, buses

Simple question - why are passengers in a bus allowed to not wear a seatbelt? 
In Slovenia, I have never heard of anyone receiving a fine for not wearing a seatbelt in a bus. Seatbelts are mandatory in cars, however.

Is there a difference in safety between seatbelts in buses and other vehicles?

Comment: Where do you live?  In the UK, it appears [there is such a requirement](http://www.scotsman.com/news/uk/seatbelt-law-impossible-to-enforce-for-bus-and-coach-passengers-1-676797).

Comment: It's the law in parts of Spain, but everyone ignores it.

Comment: You should start with the opposite - why should there be a law regulating seatbelts?

Comment: In Germany, use of seat-belts in intercity buses is mandatory.

Comment: @NateEldredge On coaches, sure. Not on buses. Most buses don't have seatbelts!

Comment: Probably applicable- they believe that it [would not improve safety](https://canadasafetycouncil.org/child-safety/there-need-seat-belts-school-buses)

Comment: Looks like this question was closed, I've edited it so it's about general safety for travellers not the varied reasons behind laws of lots of different countries

Comment: Actually looks like the question was asked already: [Do seatbelts reduce the risk of injury or death in buses?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10755/do-seatbelts-reduce-the-risk-of-injury-or-death-in-buses?rq=1), no idea why that one was closed though...

Comment: Voting to reopen.  There is an answer.

Comment: @Muzer: True.  In American English the word "bus" is used for both kinds of vehicles and I forgot there was a distinction in BrE.

Comment: In Germany on coaches (not public commute) the seat belt is mandatory and not wearing it coasts a large fine. Normal inner city commuter buses don't have seat belts, but have rules about that you have to sit or hold on to something if you stand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The likely reason seatbelt usage is not common on buses is that buses are extremely safe as is. For instance [this US study](http://usa.streetsblog.org/2014/12/19/heres-how-much-safer-transit-is-compared-to-driving/#.VJiWRzEN_eZ.twitter) showed buses are many times safer than driving and that intercity buses are especially safe even for non-passengers who might be involved in crashes with them.
[image: transport fatality graph]

None the less, seatbelt usage in intercity buses is gradually becoming required across EU countries, the US and Canada. Mostly starting with requirements that all new buses be outfitted with seatbelts. Still it seems relatively uncommon that passengers actually use these and enforcement would be challenging without sending out undercover officers - which frankly seems like a lot of effort for something that is a relatively small risk vs. violations of people travelling by car or truck. However, I've personally seen people get scolded by other passengers for not using seatbelts in Sweden.

Comment: In Australia, when I was there I was told there was a nation wide law to use seatbelts in buses. Some of the drivers were very serious about it and would not drive off (or even stop when safe) when someone did not sit with his belt on. Other drivers did even admit to know that there was a nation wide law. Not sure which driver told a white lie, but I do know that I wear the belt when it is supplied, even though I do not like it.